# Destroying object

Tags: javascript, amd

There is a nice rich text editor [Scribe](https://github.com/guardian/scribe). In my app I have multiple editable divs on a page, and on every `focus` event on particular div I want to turn this div into editable mode with Scribe. However on `blur` event I would like to destroy the instance of Scribe, due to the fact that having seperate instance for every div will be high memory consuming.

This is my AMD module which attaches Scribe instance to given DOM element:

```
define(['scribe'], function (Scribe) {

    'use strict';

    function init(element) {
        var scribe = new Scribe(element, { allowBlockElements: true });
        //...    
    }

    return {
        attachEditor: init
    };
});
```

This is piece of code which makes use of module above:

```
$('.editable').focus(function(e) {
  editorModule.attachEditor(e.target);
});
```

And now I can't figure out how to detach or destroy existing Scribe instance. I tried with this code:

```
define(['scribe'], function (Scribe) {

    'use strict';
    var scribe;
    function init(element) {
        scribe = new Scribe(element, { allowBlockElements: true });
        //...    
    }

    function destroy() {
        scribe = null;
    }

    return {
        attachEditor: init,
        detachEditor: destroy,
    };
});
```

hoping that assigning null to variable will tell the GC to remove the object. I doubt this is a good way - when I take memory snapshot in Chrome I can still see Scribe instance.

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete the object yourself. If you set all of the variables referencing it to `null`, it will be automatically deleted. The object is most likely still there because there are other references to it in the code somewhere. If you can't find the other references, you can make it just an empty object, before setting `scribe` to null like this:

```
function destroy() {
   for(var i in scribe)
   {
       delete scribe[i];
   }
   scribe = null;
}
```

That will at least free up some memory. The only way to truly get rid of it is to set all variables referencing it to `null`.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: If the variable goes out of scope, it is qualified for garbage collection as well. No need for setting anything to `null`.

Comment: @IngoBurk Setting it to null is just a heuristic. Going out of scope sets its value to `undefined` which is yet another way to remove the reference to the object. Once all references are removed, then it will be garbage collected.

Comment: I tried your way and it indeed frees up some memory, but I can still see this object (even almost empty) in memory snapshot. I don't like to leave this kind of trash :) I'm confused - object is almost empty and I set variable referencing to it to `null`, but it still exists in memory...